# Segmentation Fault in C when declaring arrays with size as a literal vs. size as a variable

Tags: c

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int *primeslessthan(int n){
  n+=1;
  int sieve[n];
  int i;
  for(i=2;i<n;i++ ){
    sieve[i]=0;
  }
  sieve[0]=1;
  sieve[1]=1;

  i = 2;
  int l = n/2;
  //int pr[10000];
  int pr[l];
  pr[0] = i;
  int count = 0;
  while(i<n){
    if(sieve[i]==0){
      count++;
      pr[count]= i;
      //printf("%i\n",i);
      int k=i*i;
      while(k<n){
        sieve[k]=1;
        //printf("Multiples of %i, %i \n",i,k);
        k+=i;
      }
    }
    i+=1;

  }
count++;
pr[count]=-1; // sentinel value.
}


int main(){
  long int num = 600851475143;
  //int a = sqrt(600851475143)+1;
  //printf("%i",a);
  int *p;
  p = (int *)malloc(20000 * sizeof(int));
  p = primeslessthan(20000);
  while((*p)!=-1){
    //printf("%i\n",*p);
    if (num%*p==0){
      num/=(*p);
      if (num==1){
        printf("p is %i\n",*p);
      }
    }
    p++;
  }
  printf("n is %ld\n",num);

}
```

the issue is this part

```
int l = n/2;
//int pr[10000];
int pr[l];
```

int pr[l]; works when n = 20000 (which would create an array with size 10000 since n = 20000) but using int pr[10000] gives a segmentation fault. I need help understanding why.
My compiler is gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Comment: A lot of code, use a debugger.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: A _declaration_ never invokes undefined behaviour. You mean a _definition_.

Comment: Your function does not return anything. Your compiler should warn already. **Always** enable warnings and pay heed to them!

Comment: what compiler settings are you using? is this c90?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Flikk: VLA's as in: `int sieve[n];` are only part of C99 standard, so we can only assume C99. no ANSI, C89/C90, no C11

Comment: regarding these two lines: `p = (int*)malloc(20000 * sizeof(int));  p = primeslessthan(20000);`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.  2) the pointer returned from malloc() is being overlayed by the call to `primeslessthan(20000)`  this results in a memory leak.  3) even without that logic error, the allocated memory is never passed to `free()` so it would still be a memory leak.  5) as mentioned in a prior comment, in C, the returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.

Answer (score 4):

For the first look, I suppose that root of problem is in the following lines:

```cpp
  int *p;
  p = (int *)malloc(20000 * sizeof(int));
  p = primeslessthan(20000);
```

I see, that after allocation made with `malloc`, pointer `p` is rewritten with value returned by `primeslessthan`. So, check that code carefully

Answer (score 0):

Change your function declaration to:

```
void primeslessthan(int n, int *pr)
```

Remove `pr` redeclaration from its code. Change the call to

```
primeslessthan(20000, p);
```

This way it should work.

Answer (score 0):

i see that your function doesn't return `int*`, and your are using this value in the ain in :
`p = primeslessthan(20000);`

Answer (score 0):

following the posted algorithm and cleaning up the 'oops' in the code and simplifying as much as I could, resulted in the following.

Note: the sequence of primes that result in `num` == 1 is: `71`, `839`, `1471`, `6857`

so the smallest number passed to `primeslessthan()` to achieve the goal is `6758`,

There are a small set of values that can be passed to `primeslessthan()` that will result in a core dump.  I.E.  do not pass a prime number to `primeslessthan()`.   I'll leave that to you to debug.

smaller values passed to `primeslessthan()` do not cause the core dump, but do not reach the goal of reducing `num` to 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // memset()
#include <math.h>

int *primeslessthan(int n)
{
    n+=1;
    int *sieve = NULL;

    if(  NULL == (sieve = calloc( (size_t)n, sizeof(int) ) ) )
    {// then calloc failed
        perror( "calloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful

    sieve[0]=1;
    sieve[1]=1;

    int i;

    for( i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(sieve[i]==0)
        {
            printf( "disregarding multiples of prime: %i\n", i );
            int k=i+i;

            while(k<n)
            {
                sieve[k]=1;
                k+=i;
            }
            sieve[i] = i;
        }
    }

    sieve[i]=-1; // sentinel value.
    return sieve;
}


int main( void )
{
    long int num = 600851475143;

    int *primes = primeslessthan(6858);

    for( unsigned i=0; primes[i] != -1; i++ )
    {
        if ( primes[i] != 1 && (num % primes[i]) == 0 )
        {
            num /= primes[i];
            printf( "prime[i]: %d, i: %d, num=%ld\n",
                   primes[i],
                   i,
                   num);
        }
    }

    printf("num is %ld\n",num);
    free(primes);
}  // end function: main
```